# Ler do arquivo e usar as partes lidas para chamar funções

Tags: c, arquivo

Tenho um arquivo que contém chamadas para funções presentes no meu código. Alguns exemplos de funções são `criar(), inserir(elemento, conjunto), listar(conjunto)` onde os argumentos são números inteiros passados para a função. Essas funções devem ser chamadas através do `arquivo.txt` que conterá, por exemplo:

`criar()
inserir(1,0)
listar(0)`

Para ler o arquivo, usei a seguinte função:

```
void leArquivo(){
FILE *arq;

    if((arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r")) == NULL)
            printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.\n");

    char buffer[100];
    char *p;

    while (fscanf (arq, "%s\n", buffer) != EOF) {
            p = buffer;
            printf("%s\n", p);    
    }    
    fclose (arq);
}
```

Porém, isso só printa o "nome" da função em si, e não a chama. Por exemplo, se no arquivo a função é `criar()`, ele printa `criar()` e não o retorno da função criar. Achei que, como `printf("%d", criar());` retorna o valor da função, `printf("%d\n", p);` retornaria o mesmo, mas não.

Pensei em usar a função `strcmp()` para poder comparar se os nomes são iguais e daí sim chamar a função, e tive sucesso nas funções sem argumentos, mas não sei como fazer para funções do tipo `inserir(elemento, conjunto)`, onde não é possível "prever" os argumentos. Alguma sugestão sobre como chamar essas funções à partir da leitura do arquivo?

Comment: Mostre seu código de forma que dê para analisar melhor o que está fazendo. Deixe ele em estado que possa ser compilado e executado até onde conseguiu. Mas já posso adiantar que você está longe do resultado. Vai ter que analisar a *string* e decidir o que fazer. Ou seja, terá que fazer alguma forma de *parser*. Não é algo tão simples.

Comment: É que achei que o que as funções em si faziam não faria diferença, visto que todas retornam apenas inteiros que devem ser exibidos. O problema é realmente chamá-las à partir do arquivo. :(

Comment: A idéia do strcmp é o caminho mais comum pra estas coisas, se a linguagem das funcoes nao for complexa demais. Compara a string num if (ou switch) e caso verdadeiro chama a função (fazendo isso uma a uma). O que pode ajudar é mexer na sintaxe, deixando as funções do mesmo tamanho e com parametros na mesma ordem (mas ai vai do caso concreto).

Answer (score 0):

Veja se a função abaixo serve para a sua necessidade:

esse trecho de código vai ler o arquivo de texto e procurar a função numa estrutura já definida e executa o comando se ele existir.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

typedef void cmd_function_t(char *);

//estrutura dos comandos
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    cmd_function_t *func;
} command_t;

static void execute_command(char *line);
static command_t *find_command(char *name);

//comandos para rodar
static void comando1(char *arg);
static void comando2(char *arg);
static void comando3(char *arg);
static void comando4(char *arg);

command_t commands[] = {
        { "comando1", comando1 },
        { "comando2", comando2 },
        { "comando3", comando3 },
        { "comando4", comando4 },
};

static command_t *find_command(char *name) {
    register int i;
    size_t namelen;

    if ((name == NULL) || (*name == '\0'))
        return ((command_t *) NULL);

    namelen = strlen(name);
    for (i = 0; commands[i].name; i++) {
        if (strncmp(name, commands[i].name, namelen - 1) == 0) {
            /* make sure the match is unique */
            if ((commands[i + 1].name)
                    && (strncmp(name, commands[i + 1].name, namelen) == 0))
                return ((command_t *) NULL);
            else
                return (&commands[i]);
        }
    }

    return ((command_t *) NULL);
}

//função que pega o texto encontrado e executa
static void execute_command(char *line) {

    register int i;
    command_t *command;
    char *word;

    /* Isolate the command word. */
    i = 0;
    while (line[i] && whitespace(line[i]))
        i++;
    word = line + i;

    while (line[i] && !whitespace(line[i]))
        i++;

    if (line[i])
        line[i++] = '\0';

    command = find_command(word);

    if (!command) {
        return;
    }

    /* Get argument to command, if any. */
    while (whitespace(line[i]))
        i++;

    word = line + i;

    /* invoke the command function. */
    (*command->func)(word);
}

static void comando1(char *arg) {

    printf("\nExecutando o Comando 1\n");
    fflush(NULL);
}

static void comando2(char *arg) {

    printf("\nExecutando o Comando 2\n");
    fflush(NULL);
}

static void comando3(char *arg) {

    printf("\nExecutando o Comando 3\n");
    fflush(NULL);
}

static void comando4(char *arg) {

    printf("\nExecutando o Comando 4\n");
    fflush(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *cmd;

    fp = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        if (line == NULL) {
            printf("Sem comando\n");
        }

        cmd = line;

        if (*cmd) {
            execute_command(cmd);
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: Eu não testei o seu código, mas acredito que ele funcione (até porque o problema do AP é um tanto trivial). Mas, pra ganhar o meu +1, você precisaria ao menos explicar detalhes de como o seu código funciona. No meu ponto de vista, a ideia do SOPt é também difundir conhecimento, e não apenas compartilhar código. :) Seria importante o AP entender o que acontece, e principalmente ter sua dúvida principal (porque `printf` de um texto não é a mesma coisa que chamar uma função?) respondida.